# Why does a part of my python code leave an emtpy line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wrote a simple guessing game. The problem is when I run the code and make three wrong guesses the program just leaves an empty line instead of printing "You lost" like I wrote in the code.

```
guess = ""
secret_word = "fist"
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
while guess != secret_word and guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess = input("Enter a guess: ")
    if guess == secret_word:
        print("You win!")
    elif guess_count > guess_limit:
        print("You lost")
    guess_count += 1
```

What's also interesting is that when I change `guess_count < guess_limit` in the fifth line to `guess_count <= guess limit` it actually does print "You lost" but obviously gives 4 attempts instead of 3. Of course, I can simply make `guess_limit` equal to 2, but that's not why I'm asking this question.

Comment: `guess_count > guess_limit` can never be reached inside a loop that only runs while `guess_count < guess_limit`, unless `guess_count` is incremented *before* that line is reached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1st attempt, guess count = 1, at the end; second attempt, guess count = 2 at the end; third attempt, guess count reaches 3 after the condition guess_count> guess limit, so it won't print you lost. so at the next loop, we have guess_count = 3 and your guess_count is no longer smaller than guess_limit so it won't enter the while loop again and nothing is printed

Comment: what you should do, is put guess_count += 1 at the beggining of your while loop

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try the following code for your case of output that you need.

**Code**

```
guess = ""
secret_word = "fist"
guess_count = 1
guess_limit = 3
while guess != secret_word:
    guess = input("Enter a guess: ")
    if guess == secret_word:
        print("You win!")
    elif guess_count >= guess_limit:
        print("You lost")
        break
    guess_count += 1
```

I've tested it and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
guess = ""
secret_word = "fist"
guess_count = 0
guess_limit = 3
while guess != secret_word and guess_count < guess_limit:
    guess_count += 1
    guess = input("Enter a guess: ")
    if guess == secret_word:
        print("You win!")
    elif guess_count >= guess_limit:
        print("You lost")
```

I just made few changes in your code hopefully it will work in your case